# Ejabberd Default Password

Tags: password, ejabberd

What is the default password for the ejabberd user created on your system when installed from the repository? I'm running Xenial Xereus 16.04.

For clarity's sake, I want to run ejabberdctl without using sudo as root.

Comment: Did you setup admin user ?

Comment: No. I'm looking for the password for the ejabberd user on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the username is added to your system without a password given. I just had my admin change the password as root.

Answer (score 1):

For the username, check the `ejabberd.yml` file in the conf directory under your ejabberd installation directory, usually `/opt/ejabberd/`.
Default username is `admin@<your_system_hostname>`
Default password is `admin`.

Comment: It was that `@<your_system_hostname>` that blocked me for hours until I read this. :)